# How to show ActionBar in TabActivity?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have created a `TabActivity` with two tabs. Their contents are two separate Activities. All working fine. But I want to show `ActionBar` on top of my `TabActivity`.
My Screenshot is [image]

Please anyone tell how to add `ActionBar` on top of my activity.
I've provided my code here.

> My Activity is

```
public class StatusReport extends TabActivity {

TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec tabOnline;
TabHost.TabSpec tabOffline;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_report);

    tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    tabOnline = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    tabOnline.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabOnline.setIndicator("E-Mail",getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    Intent in1=new Intent(StatusReport.this,OnlineDevices.class);
    tabOnline.setContent(in1);

    tabOffline = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    tabOffline.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabOffline.setIndicator("Messages",getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    Intent in2=new Intent(StatusReport.this,OfflineDevices.class);
    tabOffline.setContent(in2);

    tabHost.addTab(tabOnline);
    tabHost.addTab(tabOffline);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommand you to use PagerSlidingTabStrip.
You can find it from here: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

You can use this with toolbar.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the extends TabActivity to AppCompatActivity

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container);

sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
```